# how to add dynamic data to mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

I am trying to implement a "restaurant" table that has a menu_id that is used by an "items" table to get particular items of that menu_id. My question is: would storing all the items of all the restaurants in the "items" table be inefficient? Is there a way that I could somehow have different tables for each particular restuarant with its own items? Or would it be okay having it the way im approaching the problem. As the restaurant adds more items to their menu, the "items" table might grow large and i fear that i would have performance issues later on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Having all of the items in the items table is the way to go.

If you had one table for items per restaurant, you would also have to have a different table name in each query retrieving items per restaurant. However, with all in one table, you only have to change the restaurant you're referring to, to get a full list of its items.

About performance issues it's kind of hard to tell (and I'm no expert), but I'd say you really don't have to worry unless you're planning on having several tens of thousands of records. But then it would mean you have hundreds if not thousands of restaurants and the other way of having one table per would be messy and not all-round better performance wise.